# Does Waze api provide coordinates for pins displayed in app?

Tags: waze

Let's say I need a list of names and coordinates of all the gas stations displayed in the waze app for the state of Florida.

Does the waze api offer this information?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you are looking for such functionality in the wrong location. The Waze API is an API to start navigating, not to get a list of POIs. Waze treats that data as mission critical data and as such doesn't share this data to the outside world (except for academic purposes, I'd assume).

The Google Places API is a much better starting point for what you're trying to do. But that is outside the scope of this answer. It is also very likely that most petrol station chains will have a list of their stations available somewhere on their site, which would be an even better (= more up to date) source than Google Places. But it would require extra work to find and process all of that, of course.

Any solution with the Waze API for this purpose is going to be against the Waze Terms of Service though, so I'd advice against going further in that direction.